# Calculate mean across rows with NA values in R

Tags: r

I have a really simple R question but I can't seem to find an adequate solution. Let's say we have the following data frame:

```
groupid<-rep(1:5, each=3)
names<-rep(c("Bill", "Jim", "Sarah", "Mike", "Jennifer"),3)
test1<-rep(c(90, 70, 90, NA, 100),3)
test2<-rep(c(80, NA, 92, 80, 65), 3)
testscores<-data.frame(groupid, names, test1, test2)

groupid    names test1 test2

1        1     Bill    90    80
2        1      Jim    70    NA
3        1    Sarah    90    92
4        1     Mike    NA    80
5        1 Jennifer   100    65
6        2     Bill    90    80
7        2      Jim    70    NA
8        2    Sarah    90    92
9        2     Mike    NA    80
10       2 Jennifer   100    65
11       3     Bill    90    80
12       3      Jim    70    NA
13       3    Sarah    90    92
14       3     Mike    NA    80
15       3 Jennifer   100    65
```

We are interested in getting the mean across rows (adding an extra column to the data frame) for each test, ignoring the NA values. For example, 'Jim' would have value of 70 for his average and 'Mike' would have a value of 80. All the others would be averaged normally.

I tried using transform from the plyr package but it did not appear to accommodate the NA issue.

Comment: look at `rowMeans` setting `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: ok, I did look at that...did not see that you could pass 'na.rm'. Thanks Davide!

Answer (score 12):

```
testscores$testMean <- rowMeans(testscores[,3:4], na.rm=TRUE)
> testscores
   groupid    names test1 test2 testMean
1        1     Bill    90    80     85.0
2        1      Jim    70    NA     70.0
3        1    Sarah    90    92     91.0
4        2     Mike    NA    80     80.0
5        2 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
6        2     Bill    90    80     85.0
7        3      Jim    70    NA     70.0
8        3    Sarah    90    92     91.0
9        3     Mike    NA    80     80.0
10       4 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
11       4     Bill    90    80     85.0
12       4      Jim    70    NA     70.0
13       5    Sarah    90    92     91.0
14       5     Mike    NA    80     80.0
15       5 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
```

Comment: I just want to add that command na.rm=TRUE is possible to use also in mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)

Answer (score 3):

you can also use this

```
testscores <- structure(list(groupid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), names = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Bill", 
"Jennifer", "Jim", "Mike", "Sarah"), class = "factor"), test1 = c(90, 
70, 90, NA, 100, 90, 70, 90, NA, 100, 90, 70, 90, NA, 100), test2 = c(80, 
NA, 92, 80, 65, 80, NA, 92, 80, 65, 80, NA, 92, 80, 65)), .Names = c("groupid", 
"names", "test1", "test2"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

testscores$meanTest=rowMeans(testscores[,c("test1", "test2")], na.rm=TRUE)

#   groupid    names test1 test2 meanTest
#1        1     Bill    90    80     85.0
#2        1      Jim    70    NA     70.0
#3        1    Sarah    90    92     91.0
#4        2     Mike    NA    80     80.0
#5        2 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
#6        2     Bill    90    80     85.0
#7        3      Jim    70    NA     70.0
#8        3    Sarah    90    92     91.0
#9        3     Mike    NA    80     80.0
#10       4 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
#11       4     Bill    90    80     85.0
#12       4      Jim    70    NA     70.0
#13       5    Sarah    90    92     91.0
#14       5     Mike    NA    80     80.0
#15       5 Jennifer   100    65     82.5
```