# How to ignore missing values in dplyr without removing rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Note: The date format is DD.MM.

I have the following data frame containing stock price data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("01.01.", "02.01.", "03.01.", "04.01.", "05.01.", "06.01."),
                  A = c(102, 103, 107, NA, 120, 134),
                  B = c(94, NA, 95, 100, 93, 90),
                  C = c(55, 53, 50, 51, 48, 15))
```

In order to normalize these across time, I'm using the following formula: `x-mean(x) / sd(x)`

I have the following code to apply this function to all relevant columns:

```
df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = A:C,
                .f = function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
                ))
```

However, for those columns that have at least one `NA`, it returns the entire column as NA. I've tried adding:

```
df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = A:C,
                .f = function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
                ), na.rm  = TRUE)
```

But the same thing still happens. I don't want to use `na.omit` because I do need all the data available. How can I successfully apply the above function/one similar to it?

Comment: Add `na.rm = TRUE` in mean and sd. `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate mean across rows with NA values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458644/calculate-mean-across-rows-with-na-values-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Add `na.rm = TRUE` inside the function e.g.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = A:C,
                .f = function(x){(x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)}
  ))
```

**Output**:

```
    date          A          B          C
1 01.01. -0.8196829 -0.1096817  0.6420708
2 02.01. -0.7464969         NA  0.5092286
3 03.01. -0.4537530  0.1645225  0.3099652
4 04.01.         NA  1.5355438  0.3763863
5 05.01.  0.4976646 -0.3838859  0.1771230
6 06.01.  1.5222682 -1.2064987 -2.0147739
```